# "As 'Fieldname'" doesn't show in dataset

Tags: sql, .net, database, vb.net

The following code works fine as long as I don't use 'As Total' in the sql statement. Any column name works fine.

```
           'Get the total number of trusses this type
            sql2 = "SELECT max(sequencenumber) as Total from fitapieces fs WHERE fs.projectnumber = " & TempPieceInfo.ProjectNumber & " And fs.buildingtype = '" & TempPieceInfo.BuildingType & "' And " &
                   " fs.buildingnumber = '" & TempPieceInfo.BuildingNumber & "' And fs.buildinglevel = '" & TempPieceInfo.BLevel & "' And fs.batch = '" & TempPieceInfo.Batch & "' and fs.trussname = '" & TempPieceInfo.Trussname & "'"

            myDataset2 = SelectFromDB(sql)

            If Not myDataset2 Is Nothing Then
                If myDataset2.Tables("CurData").Rows.Count > 0 Then

                    TempPieceInfo.TotalNumberofTrussesThisType = myDataset2.Tables("CurData").Rows(0).Item("Total").ToString.Trim
                End If
            End If
```

When I use 'As Total' I get the error that "Total" doesn't belong to the table 'CurData'.

[image]

What is different about using the 'As' clause when using a dataset?

Comment: Should the variable 'sql2' be 'sql' instead?

Comment: Are you sure `SelectFromDB` is filling the `CurData` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is contained in variable `sql2` while the `SelectFromDB` method gets the paramater `sql`. This must be causing the issue. Please change the parameter name to `sql2` in the `SelectFromDB` method.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: You shouldn't code the day before a holiday. Jeez that was a dumb mistake! Thanks!